# CakePhp:Users login functionality

Tags: cakephp

```
<div>//login.ctp
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Register'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('username'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('password'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Login'); ?>
```

this is login page of my application.
     If i give invalid details or valid details it logged in to home.please help hear..

```
public function login(){
 if($this->Auth->loggedIn()){
 $this->redirect(array('action' => 'home'));
 }
 if($this->request->is('post')){
 if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)) {
 $this->Session->write('Register',$this->request->data);
 $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Registers','action' => 'home'));
 } else {
 $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
 }
 }
```

}
this is RegistersController page..

Comment: Ill recommend you to destroy session from browser then execute this code

Comment: is this correct code?

Comment: yes it is looking good. May i know cake version ?

Comment: `if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)) {}` You are number 2031 who does that one wrong. Bad bad bad. Its equal to "we dont use passwords to login". Please read the docs - carefully!

Comment: i did like that ,but i we give correct  details  that will show error msg.

Answer (score 0):

change your form as below --

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Register'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.username'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.password'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Login'); ?>
```

and check that in your AUTH component you have setted the model name to 'User' and fields mapped to Auth component settings -- and in your login function

```
$this->Session->write('Register',$this->request->data); this line is not needed any more.
```

go on below link for detail --
   http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html